# How to prove that a function is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove:

$$f= \sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k \phi_{\{r_k\}} $$

where $c_k$ and $r_k$ is constant and $\phi$ is the characteristic or indicator function.

Attempt: first prove that $\phi$ is measurable then use the theorem that if we let $c$ be constant and $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, then $cf + dg$ is measurable. Now, with the given assumptions above, how to prove the measurability of $\phi$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is really all you need: the characteristic function of a measureable set (e.g. singletons, intervals) are measurable, and linear combinations of (finitely-many) measurable functions are measurable too.

Your function $f$ is hence a linear combination of measurable functions.

---

To prove that $\phi_E$ is measurable for any measurable set $E$, just do so by definition. We know that $\phi_E$ is measurable if $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \phi_E(x) > r \}$ is a measurable set for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$. So break it up into cases:

- One case is where $r\ge 1$ (since $\phi_E(x)$ is always $0$ or $1$)
- Another case is where $0 \le r < 1$
- One more is where $r<0$

Find the preimages in each case (which should be $\varnothing,E,\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively) and justify their measurability to conclude.

Hence, that aside, it is enough to know that singletons and intervals are measurable. (Question for you to chew on: Why only measurable $E$? Consider the result of the second case above.)

Comment: Supposed it is already given that the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable, what I'm left to do is to justify that the Es, the singleton and the interval, are measurable?

Comment: $E$ is given to be measurable in that context, but otherwise yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be a Borel set and $\phi_B$ denote the indicator function on $B$. Take any real number $c$. If we can prove that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \phi(x)>c\} $ is a Borel set, then $\phi$ is measurable. One could do this by splitting the proof into different cases: $c<0$, $0\leq c<1$ and, finally, $1\leq c$.

Moreover, if $a<b$, then $(a,b)$ is Borel measurable since the Borel sets, by definition, are generated by the open intervals. Using this it is not hard to show that $\{a\}$ is a countable intersection of measurable sets and thus also measurable.